# How to resolve package conflict between joda-time and org.joda

Tags: java, maven, osgi, jodatime

When I start my application, virgo throw the exception like this:

```
[2015-09-05 11:27:53.254]  TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1 <DE0002E> Installation of bundle 'com.onboard.web.api' version '3.0.0.SNAPSHOT' failed. org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.UnableToSatisfyBundleDependenciesException: Unable to satisfy dependencies of bundle 'com.onboard.web.api' at version '3.0.0.SNAPSHOT': Cannot resolve: com.onboard.web.api
Resolver report:
    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda; version="0.0.0"> in bundle <com.onboard.web.api_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT[1441423661083]>
        Found conflicts:
            package        'org.joda.time_1.6.0' in bundle 'com.springsource.org.joda.time_1.6.0[89]' used by 'org.springframework.format.datetime.joda_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.context_3.1.0.RELEASE[60]'
            conflicts with 'org.joda.time_2.3.0' in bundle 'joda-time_2.3.0[147]' used by 'com.onboard.service.github_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT' in bundle 'com.onboard.service.github_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT[189]'
            package        'org.joda.time_1.6.0' in bundle 'com.springsource.org.joda.time_1.6.0[89]' used by 'org.springframework.format.datetime.joda_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.context_3.1.0.RELEASE[60]'
            conflicts with 'org.joda.time_2.3.0' in bundle 'joda-time_2.3.0[147]' used by 'com.onboard.service.github_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT' in bundle 'com.onboard.service.github_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT[189]'
            package        'org.joda.time.format_1.6.0' in bundle 'com.springsource.org.joda.time_1.6.0[89]' used by 'org.springframework.format.datetime.joda_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.context_3.1.0.RELEASE[60]'
            conflicts with 'org.joda.time.format_2.3.0' in bundle 'joda-time_2.3.0[147]' imported by bundle 'com.onboard.web.api_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT[1441423661083]'
            package        'org.joda.time.format_1.6.0' in bundle 'com.springsource.org.joda.time_1.6.0[89]' used by 'org.springframework.format.datetime.joda_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.context_3.1.0.RELEASE[60]'
            conflicts with 'org.joda.time.format_2.3.0' in bundle 'joda-time_2.3.0[147]' imported by bundle 'com.onboard.web.api_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT[1441423661083]'
            package        'org.springframework.core.convert.converter_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.core_3.1.0.RELEASE[61]' used by 'org.springframework.format.datetime.joda_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.context_3.1.0.RELEASE[60]'
            conflicts with 'org.springframework.core.convert.converter_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.core_3.1.0.RELEASE[112]' used by 'org.springframework.web.servlet.tags_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.web.servlet_3.1.0.RELEASE[168]'
            package        'org.springframework.core.convert.converter_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.core_3.1.0.RELEASE[61]' used by 'org.springframework.format.datetime.joda_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.context_3.1.0.RELEASE[60]'
            conflicts with 'org.springframework.core.convert.converter_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.core_3.1.0.RELEASE[112]' used by 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.web.servlet_3.1.0.RELEASE[168]'
            package        'org.joda.time_1.6.0' in bundle 'com.springsource.org.joda.time_1.6.0[89]' used by 'org.springframework.format.datetime.joda_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.context_3.1.0.RELEASE[111]'
            conflicts with 'org.joda.time_2.3.0' in bundle 'joda-time_2.3.0[147]' used by 'com.onboard.service.github_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT' in bundle 'com.onboard.service.github_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT[189]'
            package        'org.joda.time_1.6.0' in bundle 'com.springsource.org.joda.time_1.6.0[89]' used by 'org.springframework.format.datetime.joda_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.context_3.1.0.RELEASE[111]'
            conflicts with 'org.joda.time_2.3.0' in bundle 'joda-time_2.3.0[147]' used by 'com.onboard.service.github_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT' in bundle 'com.onboard.service.github_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT[189]'
            package        'org.joda.time.format_1.6.0' in bundle 'com.springsource.org.joda.time_1.6.0[89]' used by 'org.springframework.format.datetime.joda_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.context_3.1.0.RELEASE[111]'
            conflicts with 'org.joda.time.format_2.3.0' in bundle 'joda-time_2.3.0[147]' imported by bundle 'com.onboard.web.api_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT[1441423661083]'
            package        'org.joda.time.format_1.6.0' in bundle 'com.springsource.org.joda.time_1.6.0[89]' used by 'org.springframework.format.datetime.joda_3.1.0.RELEASE' in bundle 'org.springframework.context_3.1.0.RELEASE[111]'
            conflicts with 'org.joda.time.format_2.3.0' in bundle 'joda-time_2.3.0[147]' imported by bundle 'com.onboard.web.api_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT[1441423661083]'

    Uses violation: <Import-Package: org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl; version="0.0.0"> in bundle <com.onboard.web.api_3.0.0.SNAPSHOT[1441423661083]>
         Resolver reported uses conflict for import constrained to bundle <com.springsource.org.hibernate.validator> constrained bundle version range "[4.2.0.Final,4.2.0.Final]"

at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.resolve.internal.QuasiResolveStage.process(QuasiResolveStage.java:46)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.CompensatingPipeline.doProcessGraph(CompensatingPipeline.java:73)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.driveInstallPipeline(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:359)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.doInstall(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:185)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.install(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:140)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.deploy(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:253)
at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.management.StandardDeployer.deploy(StandardDeployer.java:52)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:193)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:175)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:117)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:54)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I found that I have two denpendencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.onboard</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.onboard.domain.model</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.springsource.org.hibernate.validator</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Model dependency joda-time:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And hibernate.validator dependency org.joda:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.springsource.org.joda.time</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

the version of Joda-time is 2.3, and version of org.joda is 1.6.0. Joda-time and org.joda both provide the package `org.joda.time...`. But the maven bundle plugin build the `MANIFEST.MF` only have the joda time package like this:

```
org.joda.time;version="[2.3,3)",org.joda.time.format;version="[2.3,3)"
```

So when the application start, they conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to have this two bundles? 
I tried to install com.springsource.org.hibernate.validator with joda-time and it looks to work as expect. In other hand, if you think that removing com.springsource.org.joda.time is a bad idea you can remove joda-time and use only com.springsource.org.joda.time.

In alternative you can make a bundle that includes joda-time and com.springsource.org.joda.time.
Using [BND](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) bundle plugin you can make something like that:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.springsource.org.joda.time</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${bundle-plugin.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <_failok>true</_failok>
        ...
        <Export-Package>org.joda.time*</Export-Package>
        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile</Embed-Dependency>
        ...
      </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Hope it helps!